# SASS for function for text font-weight with steps

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I want to iterate `font-weight` - 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 and 900

This is the function I'm using

```
   @for $i from 100 through 900 {
    .font-weight-#{$i} {
       font-weight: 0 + ($i * 1);
      }
    }
```

problem is, it's integrating from 100, 101, 102 to all the way to 900. How can I make this function more performant? How to output only ***100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 and 900*** values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is to iterate from 1 through 9 and multiply it by 100.

```
@for $i from 1 through 9 {
   .font-weight-#{$i * 100} {
      font-weight: ($i * 100);
   }
}
```

Comment: Somehow, I forgot to think this way.  Thanks